# UPDATE SQL not working on Node-RED Bluemix

Tags: sql, sql-update, ibm-cloud, node-red

I've a Node-RED application that has a UPDATE statement that only works the first time after Node-RED deployment, on additional executions UPDATE isn't "committed".

**Table in SQL DB ("SQL DB BN"):**

```
CREATE TABLE CORRIDA (
  MASTER VARCHAR(10),
  ESTADO VARCHAR(10),
  PLAYER VARCHAR(10),
  PONTOS INT );
```

**INSERT to create debug row:**

```
INSERT INTO CORRIDA VALUES ("LMM", "INICIO", "LMM", 0);
```

**Code in Node-RED - click inject to execute UPDATE (setting a random number on PONTOS Column) and see result:**

> [{"id":"ec3fff17.1cc7c8","type":"function","z":"4d04a829.19941","name":"","func":"msg.payload
>   = \"UPDATE CORRIDA SET PONTOS = \" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) \n    + \" WHERE PLAYER = '\" + \"LMM\" + \"'\";\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":"1","noerr":0,"x":391,"y":546,"wires":[["90698116.09c58","a7bd54cc.d207b"]]},{"id":"ad39d58.3809428","type":"inject","z":"4d04a829.19941","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":215,"y":538,"wires":[["ec3fff17.1cc7c8"]]},{"id":"a7bd54cc.d207b","type":"debug","z":"4d04a829.19941","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"true","x":850,"y":619,"wires":[]},{"id":"90698116.09c58","type":"sqldb
>   in","z":"4d04a829.19941","service":"SQL DB
>   BN","query":"","params":"","name":"","x":581,"y":510,"wires":[["c76fde76.f446"]]},{"id":"c76fde76.f446","type":"sqldb
>   in","z":"4d04a829.19941","service":"SQL DB BN","query":"SELECT PLAYER,
>   PONTOS FROM
>   CORRIDA;","params":"","name":"","x":722,"y":540,"wires":[["a7bd54cc.d207b"]]}]

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer. 
If the Query field is empty on the sqldb node, it looks into the payload and runs it and fills in the field... so only on the first run the node looks into the payload, all subsequent runs run the same query sent on the payload of the first run.
(don't quite understand the usefulness of this feature).